# I am trying to build docker file with docker build . command, but getting error

Tags: docker, redis, dockerfile, docker-image, docker-build

Dockerfile -

```sh
FROM alpine
RUN apk add --update redis
CMD ["redis-server"]
```

Running with `docker build .` command in cmd and getting below error,

```
\redis-image>docker build .

Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/3 : FROM alpine
 ---> 6dbb9cc54074
Step 2/3 : RUN apk add --update redis
 ---> Running in 00081ad2850c
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz

ERROR: https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main: temporary error (try again later)

WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main: No such file or directory

ERROR: https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community: temporary error (try again later)

WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community: No such file or directory

ERROR: unable to select packages:
  redis (no such package):
    required by: world[redis]
The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --update redis' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: I am getting the same error recently. Were you able to come up with a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Your Dockerfile seems to be alright. However, the package manager `apk` is not able to get the `redis` package from its repositories during build time, because it can't connect to them. It might be a temporary issue, or a network connectivity issue.

Make sure that you can access the mentioned URLs from your host first and then build the image. Also, it's better to use `docker build -t yourname:yourtag .` otherwise you'll end up with an untagged image which you can only access by ID.